# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: python, linux, urllib2

I am getting the following exception:

```
file "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

My code:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(filePath)
logText = response.read();
```

Moreover, I tried the following code as well:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(filePath)
logText = response.read();
```

I am still getting the said error.

However, I can access the `filePath` i.e. the url from windows machine using any browser. But I cannot access the same `filePath` i.e. the URL from the linux machine where I am executing my Python script. Moreover, from this linux machine I cannot even open a web browser.

**EDIT:** URL looks like this: http://tweb.mk.ca.am.polik.se/executions/6061/60583/logs/screenlog.ob1110.191120.txt

However, as I am able to access this URL from the windows machine that's why I don't think that there is any problem at the server.

Thanks!!

Comment: 503 is generated server-side, so it's likely caused by something in the URL you're using and you didn't provide that.

Comment: "_...from this linux machine I cannot even open a web browser_" -- I suggest you try a site that's more tech-support related, such as [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @ToddKnarr edited the question

Comment: I can't even get the host to resolve. It could be a Web filter that's set to deny the Linux machines Web access on the theory they don't need it, or something else entirely. Normally I'd do a `telnet tweb.mk.ca.am.polik.se 80` and if it connects try doing `GET / HTTP/1.0` and see what it says. I think this is less an HTTP or URL issue and more a basic network connectivity issue.